# Iterating across multiple matches of a regex capture group in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex pattern for pulling out the file names in the HTML source of a directory listing. However, I can't figure out how to get past the first match and grab the second match as well.

The HTML looks something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="jetty-dir.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>Directory: /custom/view/slideshow/images/</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="title">Directory: /custom/view/slideshow/images/</h1>
<table class="listing">
<thead>
<tr><th class="name"><a href="?C=N&O=D">Name&nbsp; &#8679;</a></th><th class="lastmodified"><a href="?C=M&O=A">Last Modified</a></th><th class="size"><a href="?C=S&O=A">Size</a></th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td class="name"><a href="/custom/view/slideshow/images/../">Parent Directory</a></td><td class="lastmodified">-</td><td>-</td></tr>
<tr><td class="name"><a href="/custom/view/slideshow/images/image1.png">image1.png&nbsp;</a></td><td class="lastmodified">Mar 19, 2024 4:50:48 PM&nbsp;</td><td class="size">636,207 bytes&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td class="name"><a href="/custom/view/slideshow/images/image2.png">image2.png&nbsp;</a></td><td class="lastmodified">Mar 19, 2024 12:48:06 PM&nbsp;</td><td class="size">176,020 bytes&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td class="name"><a href="/custom/view/slideshow/images/pagebanner.jpg">pagebanner.jpg&nbsp;</a></td><td class="lastmodified">Feb 4, 2024 4:35:30 PM&nbsp;</td><td class="size">73,220 bytes&nbsp;</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Here's the calling JavaScript

```
var imageList = [];

$.get('/custom/view/slideshow/images/', function(data) {
    var regEx = /\/images\/(.*\.png)">/i;
    var item;
    
    do {
        // This does not move the iterator forward. 
        // It only gets the first one
        item = regEx.exec(data); 
        
        if (item) {
            imageList.push(item[1]);
        }
        
        console.log(imageList.length + "; " + item[1]);
        // Since we never move forward, item is never 
        // null and we loop until an error condition 
        // emerges
    } while (item);
    
    for (var xx = 0; xx < imageList.length; xx++) {
        console.log(imageList[xx]);
    }
    
});
```

I would be able to pull both matches into the array of images.

Comment: Don't use Regex to parse HTML. Use a dedicated HTML parser. As you're using jQuery, you've already got access to one

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan While that's a valid approach I hadn't thought of and will likely implement, I still want to understand why it's not iterating across all of the matches in the group.

Comment: Why didn't you use `g` (global) flag?

Comment: @PM77-1 And that is what I was missing! Thank you!

Comment: Just replace function body with this: `for (let im of data.match(/(?<=\/images\/).*\.png(?=">)/gi)) console.log(im);`

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was simply to add the global flag to the regex pattern before the case-insensitive flag.

`var regEx = /\/images\/(.*\.png)">/gi;`